# Problems With Stripping Out Part of Sidebar in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Whenever I edit the 'sidebar.php' file (in an attempt to strip out the Blogroll & Meta sections of the side bar) the entire site breaks...

```
<ul>

        <?php /* If this is the frontpage */ if ( is_home() || is_page() ) { ?>
            <?php wp_list_bookmarks(); ?>
            <li><h2>Meta</h2>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_register(); ?>
                <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                <li><a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer" title="This page validates as XHTML 1.0 Transitional">Valid <abbr title="eXtensible HyperText Markup Language">XHTML</abbr></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/"><abbr title="XHTML Friends Network">XFN</abbr></a></li>

                <?php wp_meta(); ?>
            </ul>
            </li>
```

^^ That's the bit I'm trying to strip out. Any ideas why it's coming up as an error page every time I try?

Thanks - Tara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've guessing the removal of this line is the problem:

```
<?php /* If this is the frontpage */ if ( is_home() || is_page() ) { ?>
```

You're probably leaving the closing part of that `if` statement (which would a `}` ) on the page and it's causing a syntax error.

You'll either want to remove the entire `if` statement or just the content inside of it.

*(Thanks to Emil for the edit suggestion)*

Comment: Is that the finished statement there, or just part of it? If not, what would the closing part look like? Thanks

Comment: The closing part is the closing `}`

Comment: @emil Thank you! That worked. I didn't know php had closing tags like that.

Answer (score 1):

In the Admin section of Wordpress goto Appearance -> Widgets 
There in the primary widget area you can drag & drop meta or which ever widget to be disabled to the Inactive widgets area so that the meta widget will be disappeared from the front page